# Java (Netty) app hitting 11k req/second plateau

Tags: java, linux, performance, netty

I have screenshots of metrics for the last 3 days. Overnight, when traffic is below the 11k req/sec, the server works perfectly, response times are at ~0-1ms. When traffic rises above the 11k req/sec, http response times spike to ~700ms, tcp listen overflows spike, haproxy sessions spike, frontend sessions hit the haproxy configured limit or 30k. I can raise that 30k limit by changing the configuration, but that doesn't improve response latency, or traffic throughput, so I've left it at 30k. JVM memory usage is well below capacity. cpu usage peaks at about 43%. That is on a 12 core server. I presume this isn't CPU limited?

*UPDATE*: Added new CPU graph without idle time (which was confusing). Added new network graph with transmit receive bytes/sec.

[image: haproxy backend sessions]
[image: haproxy measured response times]
[image: haproxy current session counts.]
[image: tcp listen overflows]
[image: jvm memory usage]
[image: cpu usage (revised with no idle)]
[image: network bytes/sec]

Also, internal latency measurements, measured by a timer inside my code base, show responses are always handled in <1ms, even at higher traffic volumes. The graph is slightly confusing, but there are basically separate plots for responses <= 1sec, <= 0.75 sec, ..., <= 0.005 sec, <= 0.001 sec, and they are all the same since the responses are all <= 0.001 sec as measured by the timer in the application code.

[image: Internal Latency Metrics]

The server app is written in Java using the current version of Netty as of this writing, 4.1.25. haproxy 1.6.x is running in front of the app for metrics and otherwise doing simple proxying. The server is running Ubuntu 16.04.x with latest patches. I previously used the OpenJDK 8 in Ubuntu repos but now am running a downloaded version of OpenJDK 10.0.1. There isn't a noticeable difference between the two OpenJDKs.

Is there anything I can do get this server to handle larger volumes of traffic? Are there any other metrics that I can capture or settings that I can check that would help illuminate the problem?

Comment: Yes, green is idle. the legend is included in the screenshot. CPU idle goes down during the spike...

Comment: Ah, sorry - you're absolutely right; I misread the graph.

Comment: This is a total shot in the dark, but it feels like if you're getting TCP/IP overflows, then your front end is having problems.  Are you at the physical limits of what your NIC can receive and transmit?  (How much data is going in and out?)  And can you increase the number and size of buffers that the OS has to store TCP packets into so that some overflow in alleviated?